# agreement in parallel structure

Tags: parallelism, agreement

Consider this sentence:

> When I am working at the computer, where do I end and the computer begin?

The question is a parallel structure. If we unpack it, it would be

> Where do I end, and where does the computer begin?

But note that, *I* is first-person, and *computer* is third-person, so in the unpacked version, we use the auxiliary verb *do* to agree with *I*, but *does* to agree with *the computer*. However, if we want to parallelize it, we must choose one. Is this legal?

Comment: You could use "Where is it that I end and the computer begins".

Comment: @Peter very clever!

Comment: Your unpacked version is the grammatical if rather wordy variant. Peter's solution sounds more natural.

Comment: Nothing to do with the English Language question but the quote reminds me of the desktop support statement "ninety percent of all computer problems are located between the keyboard and the seat of the chair".

Comment: Not legal......